# What import statements am I missing to get this class to connect this couchbase server with my REST API?

Tags: java, spring, import, couchbase, api-design

I'm trying to connect a local Couchbase server with a Spring Boot REST API I'm building. The code I'm using is from the bottom of in the usage section: http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-couchbase/#quick-start

I think I have everything configured, I just can't get this last class to function without errors. I believe it's all related to having proper import statements, which I've only been able to figure out a few. The "user" object is having issues instantiating, stating it's abstract. Several functions based off that are therefore throwing errors. Box and Point also seem to not be able to agree on an import statement. I can only get one of them fixed at a time.

Here is the code for the class, I don't think you'll need anything from other classes:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class MyService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void doWork() {
        userRepository.deleteAll();

        User user = new User();
        user.setLastname("Jackson");
        user.setLocation(new Point(123, 456));

        user = userRepository.save(user);

        List<User> jacksonChildren =
                userRepository.findByLastNameAndAgeBetween("Jackson", 0, 18);

        List<User> jacksonFamily =
                userRepository.findByLastName("Jackson");

        //bounding box is lower-left, upper-right corners
        Box cityBounds = new Box(new Point(100, 100), new Point(150, 500));
        List<User> jacksonsInSomeCity =
                userRepository.findByLocationWithin(cityBounds);
    }
}
```

Comment: *is* your `User` class abstract? Have you tried your IDE features for simply importing the correct classes?

Comment: This is the only place where User is instantiated. I have a UserRepository interface that uses User in Lists (code for that is from the same link) and this import statement (import org.apache.catalina.User;) seems to work. But not for the MyService class. I shouldn't need to create an entire User class for this one object, should I?

Comment: that User import is probably COMPLETELY wrong. Are the User and the UserRepository not classes you yourself wrote? If you did not do that, do it now.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to get a local Couchbase server connected to my API. This: http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-couchbase/#quick-start is the only useful thing I could find. But it's missing a lot of information on how to get it running. I have no idea what else I need to add to this, and I can't find anything more informative.

Comment: Take a look at the first link in that tutorial: http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/#quick-start

Comment: I've actually already done that and am reusing a lot of stuff from that. But I suppose I'm having trouble making sense of the two and putting them together into one coherent project. Considering how informative a lot of the Spring tutorials are, I'm surprised this one isn't more inclusive.

Comment: In fact, I got the project running from that other tutorial you suggested, but was specifically unable to figure out how to use any of the CRUD operations it generated. I think even just having that pointed out would help me tremendously to understand what processes are going on here.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for specifically. I think you just have to dig through more tutorials.

Comment: Well at the bottom of the Spring Data tutorial it says:

Launch your app and Spring Data (having been autoconfigured by Boot, SQL or NoSQL) will automatically craft a concrete set of operations:

save(Employee)
delete(Employee)
find(Employee)
find(Long)
findAll()
On top of the CRUD operations inherited from CrudRepository, the interface defines two query methods.

findByFirstName(…) automatically writes a JPA query based on firstName and only return the first employee found.


How do I use the functions? Do I need another program? This is not yet connected to couchbase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User entity needs to be defined in your project. The reference documentation has an example http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#basics. Here is a sample project using Couchbase in spring boot https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-couchbase.